# Find the value of $f(x)$ with proof.

Tags: real-analysis

The equation is:

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x) - 1}{x - 2} = 3$$

Suppose f(x) is a function. Find (with proof) the value of lim x→2 f(x), or conclude that this limit diverges.

Our professor wrote in a hint stating: Use Arithmetic of Limits and contradiction. Why can't $\lim_{x\to2}
f(x) = 0$, for
instance?

It is a question from a previous midterm and noone ive spoken to has solved it,so i wanna ask you guys.

Comment: Didn't you forget a "little" detail? What is $\;f(x)\;$ , anyway?!

Comment: Its a function on x.

Comment: Then perhaps the actual question is "what is the value of $\;f(2)\;$ ..."?? Because the value of $\;f(x)\;$ cannot be known from the given info.

Comment: @ThomasShelby I saw it...read my comment below such answer. Apparently the OP meant to ask what is the value of $\;f(2)\;$ ...

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't read the question properly.@DonAntonio

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

We know that
$$
\lim_{x\to 2}(f(x)-1)=\left(\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{f(x)-1}{x-2}\right)\times\lim_{x\to2}(x-2)\tag{0}
$$
by the product rule for limits and 
$$
\lim_{x\to2}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 2}(f(x)-1)+\lim_{x\to2}1\tag{1}.
$$
You have enough information to compute all the limits.

Comment: Yes, the limits can be computed, apparently (if the OP did give all the relevant info...), yet the question seems to be **what is the value of** $\;f\;$ ...perhaps when $\;x=2\;$ or something like that.

Comment: @user569685 Great! Why then in the world didn't you write this in your question?!